# jqgrid data client server synchronize

Tags: jqgrid

jqgrid total rows count

how set to jqgrid vertical scroll bar value:
total records count=100,000 records (let say) location on record: 51,100
but acutually server send to client only 1 page (actual visible rows in client grid) ?

so :
on rowAdd server send value total records= 100,001 
or on rowDelete server send total records=99,999
same on scroll up or scroll down

but actually 'real' rows in client is always not greater then it's visible rows (10-15 rows let say)

it will be the server seponsibility to make the synchronize.

to summerize:
can jqGrid set values to vertical-scrollbar-thumb 'sees' thounds of records+ and location
but actually manage only visible rows ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager

Comment: from first look at the pager handler, it seems the tqgrid has to reload all page rows on every new row or delete row or next/prvious page. how I can handle the pager just for client view *setting value's),but make custom code for roes-in-client/records synchronize